# Local Development Server in not loading messageChannels

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I have created a message channel and referring to the LWC component.

when I try to load the component I am getting the below error message.

Error loading http://localhost:3333/webruntime/component/latest/dev/en-US/@salesforce/messageChannel/MessageChannel-Name from http://localhost:3333/webruntime/custom-component/latest/dev/en-US/c/Component-Name

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. Create a message channel.
2. Import message channel in LWC Component.
3. Open LWC Component in Local dev server.
4. The server throws an error

Expected behavior:
Component should load

Desktop
OS: MAC
Browser Chrome

Comment: LMS not support Local development, try to deploy and test in org...

Comment: Have you found a workaround to make it work with the local dev server? I get the same error...